# How to Apply Word Styles to Richtext Object? (docxtpl library)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, ms-word

I'm currently trying to generate a word document using the docxtpl. However, i cannot work out how to add a word style to the Richtext object when the style name includes a space, as the style doesn't get applied within the word document. In other cases where the style is named using a single word, it works fine.
Here is my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, RichText

html = "<html><body><p><p>I am a paragraph generated by python.</p></p><ul><li>List 1 item 1</li><li>List 1 item " \
   "2</li></ul><p>Example below:</p><li>List 2 item 1</li><li>List 2 item 1</li><p>End paragraph</p></body></html> "


def main():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').find_all()
    rt = RichText()
    for tag in soup:
        if tag.name == 'p' and tag.parent.name != 'p':
            print tag.text
            rt.add(tag.text + "\n\n")
        elif tag.name == 'li' and tag.parent.name != 'li':
            rt.add(tag.text + "\n", style='Subtle Reference')

    output_data = {"data": rt}
    tpl = DocxTemplate('template.docx')
    tpl.render(output_data)
    tpl.save('output.docx')
```

Jinja code within word document:

```
{{r data}}
```

I've created an issue on gitlab with this, but was wondering if anyone had used this library before and had any good work arounds?

Answer (score 4):

From the example files, it looks as though you can't convert an HTML string directly into RichText(). You have to use their class syntax, rather.

Here's an example:

```
rt = RichText('an exemple of ')

rt.add('a rich text', style='myrichtextstyle')
rt.add(' with ')
rt.add('some italic', italic=True)
rt.add(' and ')
rt.add('some violet', color='#ff00ff')
rt.add(' and ')
rt.add('some striked', strike=True)
rt.add(' and ')
rt.add('some small', size=14)
rt.add(' or ')
rt.add('big', size=60)
rt.add(' text.')
rt.add(' Et voilà ! ')
rt.add('\n1st line')
rt.add('\n2nd line')
rt.add('\n3rd line')
rt.add('\n\n<cool>')

context = {
    'example' : rt,
}

tpl.render(context)
tpl.save('test_files/richtext.docx')
```

Source: https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/blob/master/tests/richtext.py